# How to Configure two Twilio Dial number

Tags: post, go, get, twilio

```
type TwilioMakeCallTwiML struct {
    Say     *sayTwIML  `xml:"Say,omitempty"`
    Play    *playTwIML `xml:"Play,omitempty"`
    XMLName xml.Name   `xml:"Response"`
    Dial    struct {
        Say      *sayTwIML `xml:"Say,omitempty"`
        Timeout  int `xml:"timeout,attr"`
        CallerID string `xml:"callerId,attr"`
        Record   string `xml:"record,attr"`
        Number struct {
            StatusCallbackEvent  string `xml:"statusCallbackEvent,attr"`
            StatusCallback       string `xml:"statusCallback,attr"`
            StatusCallbackMethod string `xml:"statusCallbackMethod,attr"`
            PhoneNumber          string `xml:",chardata"`
        } `xml:"Number,omitempty"`

    } `xml:"Dial,omitempty"`
    DialVoice    struct {
        Say      string `xml:"Say,omitempty"`
        CallerID string `xml:"callerId,attr"`
        Record   string `xml:"record,attr"`
        Number struct {
            StatusCallbackEvent  string `xml:"statusCallbackEvent,attr"`
            StatusCallback       string `xml:"statusCallback,attr"`
            StatusCallbackMethod string `xml:"statusCallbackMethod,attr"`
            PhoneNumber          string `xml:",chardata"`
        } `xml:"Number,omitempty"`

    } `xml:"Dial,omitempty"`
}
```

> ttwilio.TwilioMakeCallTwiML field "Dial" with tag "Dial,omitempty"
>   conflicts with field "DialVoice" with tag "Dial,omitempty"
>   HTTP|2018/03/12 16:23:21
>   |[::1]:49370|POST|/ttwilio/receiveIncomingCall|500|21||TwilioProxy/1.1|18.924103ms|

I want to replicate this TwiML

```
<Response>
    <Say>Please wait while we're trying to connect you to the next available representative.</Say>
    <Dial timeout="20"><!--cellphone #1--></Dial>

    <Say>Please wait while we're trying to connect you to the next available representative.</Say>
    <Dial timeout="20"><!--cellphone #2--></Dial>

    <Say>Please wait while we're trying to connect you to the next available representative.</Say>
    <Dial timeout="20"><!--cellphone #3--></Dial>
</Response>
```

Comment: You have two structs with the same xml tag. This is not allowed. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: The `Dial` and `DialVoice` look very similar, can you just use one of them? How are you calling this struct to make the XML?